# Compatible Wireless Router?

Tags: linux, hardware, wifi, router

I'm looking for a wireless router for personal use. I have a small apartment and need the router primarily for my android phone connection. I might need it for streaming video as well.

I'm running Kubuntu on a ThinkPad T61p.

My wireless card is:

Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection (rev 61)

I'm looking for a reasonably feature-rich router that I will not have to change in the next 2-3 years.

Some of the brands I've been recommended so far are: 
NetGear such as  WNR3500L or 3500 
D-Link such as DIR 655 
Linksys

Any ideas? Or any up2date list?

Comment: This is probably not the right site for this question. Superuser may be more appropriate...

Comment: Could you clarify how the selection of router (hardware) is related to the OS? Is there any issue with connecting your Android device to routers suggested? It sound like general hardware advice.

Comment: This question isn't related to unix, so it's off-topic here. On [Super User](http://superuser.com/), it would probably be closed because it's a shopping recommendation. I don't think there's currently a place in the Stack Exchange network for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read Jeff's article [Because Everyone Needs a Router](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/because-everyone-needs-a-router.html) to get some ideas. In the end, he chose the Buffalo Nfiniti Wireless-N High Power Router.

Comment: The fact that she mentioned OS implies that choosing a router has something to do with the OS. Also, that SU note should be a comment.

Comment: @Tshebang - good points; I added a comment instead.